# Drawing lines for updated values in android dynamically

Tags: java, android, graph, charts

I am developing an app for driving speed. I need to draw lines like graph based on Speed and time (seconds). Time values are x-axis and speed values are y-axis. I tried for random values, its working. But if I draw this for updated values, its not working. Try to help me.
Thanks in advance!

```
class MyView extends View {


Paint paint = new Paint();
Path path = new Path();
 float[] x=new float[30];
 float[] y=new float[30];
 int i=0;

public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);

while(i<10)
   {
    x[i]= seconds; 
    y[i]= Speed;

    y[i]=(float) (0.262*y[i]); // this is for drawing my y-axis to certain range

    System.out.println("Current seconds:"+x[i]);
    System.out.println("Current speed:"+y[i]);

    seconds+= 60;  //   update for every 60 seconds
    i++;

    }
}
public void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {


       path.moveTo(x[0],y[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {

               path.lineTo(x[i],y[i]);

       }
        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        paint.setColor(0xFFFF5050);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        System.out.println("Height:"+relativelayout5.getHeight());
        canvas.translate(0,relativelayout5.getHeight());   // reset where 0,0 is located
        canvas.scale(1,-1);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
       paint.setShadowLayer(0, 0, 0, 0); 
       paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
     }  

}
```

i Invalidate this view in MainActivity.

Comment: what does this code mean y[i]= Speed;?

Comment: i stored the updated speed values in y[i]

Comment: are you getting output of  System.out.println("Current seconds:"+x[i]);
    System.out.println("Current speed:"+y[i]);

Comment: I test it in emulator, in tat i got current seconds values.  Current speed value shows 0.